# Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I get an error while training the network: `Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 50000 input samples and 25000 target samples.` 
x_train shape (50000, 200)
y_train (25000,)
x_test (50000, 200)
y_test  (25000,)
How can I correct the error?
My network written with keras
Data set load from csv files

turn lists of strings into lists of integers

x_train = [[int(elt) for elt in sublist] for sublist in x_train]

```
x_test = [[int(elt) for elt in sublist] for sublist in x_test]
y_train = [int(elt) for elt in y_train]
y_test = [int(elt) for elt in y_test]


# convert integer reviews into word reviews
x_full = x_train + x_test
x_full_words = [[index_to_word[idx] for idx in rev if idx!=0] for rev in x_full]
all_words = [word for rev in x_full_words for word in rev]
if use_pretrained:

    # initialize word vectors
    word_vectors = Word2Vec(size=word_vector_dim, min_count=1)

    # create entries for the words in our vocabulary
    word_vectors.build_vocab(x_full_words)

    # sanity check
    assert (len(list(set(all_words))) == len(word_vectors.wv.vocab)), "3rd sanity check failed!"

    # fill entries with the pre-trained word vectors
    word_vectors.intersect_word2vec_format(path_to_pretrained_wv + 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)

    print('pre-trained word vectors loaded')

    norms = [np.linalg.norm(word_vectors[word]) for word in
             list(word_vectors.wv.vocab)]  # in Python 2.7: word_vectors.wv.vocab.keys()
    idxs_zero_norms = [idx for idx, norm in enumerate(norms) if norm < 0.05]
    no_entry_words = [list(word_vectors.wv.vocab)[idx] for idx in idxs_zero_norms]
    print('# of vocab words w/o a Google News entry:', len(no_entry_words))

    # create numpy array of embeddings
    embeddings = np.zeros((max_features + 1, word_vector_dim))
    for word in list(word_vectors.wv.vocab):
        idx = word_to_index[word]
        # word_to_index is 1-based! the 0-th row, used for padding, stays at zero
        embeddings[idx,] = word_vectors[word]

    print('embeddings created')

else:
    print('not using pre-trained embeddings')
```

And model

```
#model
my_input = Input(shape=(max_size,)) # we leave the 2nd argument of shape blank because the Embedding layer cannot accept an input_shape argument

if use_pretrained:
    embedding = Embedding(input_dim=embeddings.shape[0], # vocab size, including the 0-th word used for padding
                          output_dim=word_vector_dim,
                          weights=[embeddings], # we pass our pre-trained embeddings
                          input_length=max_size,
                          trainable=not do_static,
                          ) (my_input)
else:
    embedding = Embedding(input_dim=max_features + 1,
                          output_dim=word_vector_dim,
                          trainable=not do_static,
                          ) (my_input)

embedding_dropped = Dropout(drop_rate)(embedding)

# feature map size should be equal to max_size-filter_size+1
# tensor shape after conv layer should be (feature map size, nb_filters)
print('branch A:',nb_filters,'feature maps of size',max_size-filter_size_a+1)
print('branch B:',nb_filters,'feature maps of size',max_size-filter_size_b+1)

# A branch
conv_a = Conv1D(filters = nb_filters,
              kernel_size = filter_size_a,
              activation = 'relu',
              )(embedding_dropped)

pooled_conv_a = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(conv_a)

pooled_conv_dropped_a = Dropout(drop_rate)(pooled_conv_a)

# B branch
conv_b = Conv1D(filters = nb_filters,
              kernel_size = filter_size_b,
              activation = 'relu',
              )(embedding_dropped)

pooled_conv_b = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(conv_b)

pooled_conv_dropped_b = Dropout(drop_rate)(pooled_conv_b)

concat = Concatenate()([pooled_conv_dropped_a,pooled_conv_dropped_b])

concat_dropped = Dropout(drop_rate)(concat)

# we finally project onto a single unit output layer with sigmoid activation
prob = Dense(units = 1, # dimensionality of the output space
             activation = 'sigmoid',
             )(concat_dropped)

model = Model(my_input, prob)
model.layers[4].output_shape # dimensionality of document encodings (nb_filters*2)
```

Comment: you have to post more of the source, especially where you load your x and y datasets

Comment: you need x and y to be the same length, they need to be one to one, one x for one y

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say exactly where the problem is based on what you have described about your data but there must be one target (y) for every input sample (x), and that is why you are getting the error `Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 50000 input samples and 25000 target samples.`. Your shapes (and the Keras error) show that you have 50,000 instances and only 25,000 targets.

There is either an error in the csv data or an import or processing error somewhere along the way.